# Installing software in another location?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I bought a 32gb msata ssd for my gigabyte brix (amd) and I was wondering if I were to install Ubuntu on that drive that I could install software/ packages in another location like on a secondary hard drive? I would like to keep Ubuntu on the ssd for speed and dedicate a mechanical drive for programs and files.

Comment: As far as I know, applications are installed under /usr/bin. If you mount /usr on a separate hard drive, you could effectively install and run programs from that separate hard drive.

Comment: On a sidenote, if you want to "keep Ubuntu on the SSD for speed," wouldn't you want your programs on the SSD as well? Otherwise your computer would boot quickly, but programs wouldn't.

Comment: I thought that if I dedicate the os to one drive and dedicate programs to another it would be like splitting the load between two.